# Build a shape over a shape with java3d

Tags: java-3d

Lets say I have drawn a cube or a cylinder with Java3d. I would like to for example when I click on the surface of these shapes to build a small cone over it. I would appreciate if there is some examples. 
thanks

Comment: Based on the number of views I don't think this a common scenario to grant a detailed reply, so I'll just say, use PickCanvas with a mouse listener, that will give you the coordinates on the surface then you can put there a new node.

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont have a specific code for you but you could add a action listener to the cube. then with a serperate class with the code for a cone. This is not the entirety of the code but it should provide a good example.

```
public void class random1 {
cube.addactionListener(this);
} 
public void actionlistener(ActionEvent ev)
if(ev.actionEvent = cube){
Random2 rad = new Random2();
rad.cone();
 }
 }

 public void class Random2 {
    public void cone(){
      // code for the cone has to be in here
    }
 }
```